# Spring Hello world Not working-404 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have tried simple Hello world program using spring.It is not working as expected.

```
package com.Spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class Hello {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "hello world");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Spring" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Spring.Hello</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
        <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

hello.jsp file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

I have created war file using ant and deployed.After deployed war file there is no error in the terminal.Now i have try to access URL in browser it shows 404 error.

```
http://ipaddress:8080/SpringHello/hello.jsp
```

How to access the URL? or what am i did wrong?

Comment: Try: http://ipaddress:8080/SpringHello/hello.

Comment: Thanks for reply.yes.I have tried without using .jsp.Again it shows same error 404.

Comment: Make sure, your jsp and Web-servlet.xml is in a jsp folder under WEB-INF. It that doesn't work, try removing WEB-INF entries from Web-servlet.xml and web.xml and put jsp and Web-servlet.xml in webapps folder direclty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding wrong servlet class in web.xml.

```
<servlet-class>com.Spring.Hello</servlet-class>
```

It should be :

```
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

For more understanding : http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: Without any doubt the best tutorials avaialble on the internet !

Comment: Thanks.I have changed servlet class and deployed the war.It shows WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringHello/hello/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'.

Comment: asif..Yup true.!
@ami..Try with following uri : http://ipaddress:8080/SpringHello/hello//

Comment: i.e. put forward slash after hello

Comment: Thanks Arya.tried both ways  ipaddress:8080/SpringHello/hello and  ipaddress:8080/SpringHello/hello/. It shows Dec 9, 2013 12:51:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringHello/hello/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Comment: @ami..create folder "jsp" inside WEB-INF and put your "hello.jsp" inside that folder.its working with uri:http://localhost:8080/testmvc/hello

Comment: Thanks a lot Arya.Now its worked after i changed.I cant understand this logic why am i need to create separate folder jsp?? can you explain me??

Comment: @Ami..in your HelloWeb-servlet.xml file..<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> you defined that hello.jsp is in jsp folder.

Answer (score 1):

The Handlermapping is missing in the context file, too. So add annotation-driven bean on top of what Kamlesh suggested.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```